# Spring Boot 2.3.4 - How to define [host:port] as log prefix in application.properties?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback

I am an enthusiast, been trying to customize my application's logging pattern.
I want to set the currently listening **port** along with its **hostname** as prefix to the logs
generated on console. What I tried in my application.properties is,

```
logging.pattern.console=[${HOSTNAME}:${server.port}] %d{HH:mm dd-MM-yy} <%logger{10}> : %msg%n
```

After getting the following output - **server.port_IS_UNDEFINED**,

```
[ReSSuRRecTeD:server.port_IS_UNDEFINED] 02:48 10-09-21 <c.c.s.s.ScValidationService> : Scheduled Payment Checker is in ACTION
```

I looked around to find the proper way to achieve my goal to get the currect value of the port.

Is there any way to do this, **without using extra logback/log4j(.xml) configuration** ?
If yes, how should I get the port value and define it in the the logging pattern ?

Note: I tried defining

```
server.port=0
```

But, it gives me 0 as the port value rather than the actual port on which my application is actually listening.

Many many thanks and appreciations for your valuable help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you use logback, you need first defined the spring property in logback-spring.xml as shown below :

```
<springProperty scope="context" name="SERVER_PORT" source="server.port"/>
```

Now you can use `${SERVER_PORT}` in logback-spring.xml.